# Get amount of fast retransmissions from TCP Info

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, linux-kernel, tcp

I'm trying to fetch the amount of fast retransmissions from the TCP Info struct. As there is multiple different variables that seem to hold retransmissions, I'm unsure which holds the amount of fast retransmissions (if any of them do).

These are the possible candidates:

- __u8    tcpi_retransmits;
- __u32   tcpi_retrans;
- __u32   tcpi_total_retrans;

Does any of these variables contain the amount of fast retransmits? If so, which of them?

**I want to count the amount of congestion events caused by dupacks.**

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use tcpi_retrans as is contains retransmits that occur due to fast retransmits (and other non-timeout based decisions), but I think it is often set to zero. tcpi_retransmits holds timeout based retransmits btw.

You should probably have a look at LINUX_MIB_TCPFASTRETRANS in net statistics. That one should hold the statistics you want.